# send emails to multiple recipients actionmailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I have in **invitation_mailer.rb** the next:

```
class InvitationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "email@email.com"
  def invitation_friends(invitation, user)
   @user = user
   @invitation = invitation
   mail(:bcc => @invitation.recipients.map(&:recipients), :subject => "Subject email")
  end
end
```

**@invitation.recipients** is an array with emails like:

```
 ["email1@example.com","email2@example.com"]
```

but I get in log the next:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `recipients' for "email1@example.com":String):
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Thank you!

Comment: The problem was fixed :D. The fixed is `@invitation.recipients.map { |val| p val }`. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `@invitations.recipients.join("; ")`

You are trying to call :recipients on a String-object in your array, which cannot work.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this line:

```
@invitation.recipients.map(&:recipients)
```

should actually be:

```
@invitation.recipients.join(';')
```

`map(&:recipients)` means: call #recipients method on each element in the array. You get he error since your array holds strings, and clearly String doesn't have method #recipients :)